# Rails 3.2 generators without a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to generate a resource and I have removed all references to Active_record and removed the databse.yml file.

The rails server starts ok but when I try to generate a model:

```
rails g resource contact
```

I get the following error:

> No value provided for required options '--orm'

Is there a way to specify no database when generating a resource?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way, no. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/resource_helpers.rb) for the resource generator, you'll see this part regarding the orm:

```
    # Loads the ORM::Generators::ActiveModel class. This class is responsible
    # to tell scaffold entities how to generate an specific method for the
    # ORM. Check Rails::Generators::ActiveModel for more information.
    def orm_class
      @orm_class ||= begin
        # Raise an error if the class_option :orm was not defined.
        unless self.class.class_options[:orm]
          raise "You need to have :orm as class option to invoke orm_class and orm_instance"
        end

        begin
          "#{options[:orm].to_s.camelize}::Generators::ActiveModel".constantize
        rescue NameError
          Rails::Generators::ActiveModel
        end
      end
    end
```

So it explicitly rejects any attempt to run this command without an ORM, and if you do specify an ORM, it's looking for `ORM::Generators::ActiveModel`. And in the comments at the top, it specifies a location to find more information, [Rails::Generators::ActiveModel](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/active_model.rb). The comments at the top there explain how to extend it to create an ORM specification.

The only one built-in to rails by default is [the ActiveRecord generator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record.rb).

There is a gem called [rails3-generators](https://github.com/indirect/rails3-generators) that includes generators for a number of common libraries, but you can [see](https://github.com/indirect/rails3-generators/blob/master/lib/rails3-generators.rb) that for ORMs it only adds functionality for `data_mapper`, `mongo_mapper`, `mongoid`, and `active_model`.

As far as I know, there is no pre-built ORM generator for "no database". You could write one yourself, if you want, by following the instructions at the top of `Rails::Generators::ActiveModel` (and using the `rails3-generators` gem source as a reference of you need it).

But if that seems like too much effort, I'd recommend just telling it to generate using the built-in ActiveRecord generator, and then just manually modifying/removing anything it generated related to that ORM.